# TypeError: string indices must be integers with flask json

Tags: python, json, flask

I am testing a flask app where I need to post some key value pairs, but  my flask app is expecting them in JSON format. At the command line I created json from my kv pairs like so:

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True,indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
{
    "4": 5,
    "6": 7
}
```

when I put this into postman:

[image]

and post it to my app I get:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

However if I use:

```
[{
    "4": 5,
    "6": 7
}]
```

It works! Why is this happening?

Here is the app code. the error is happening at the last line:

```
json = request.get_json(force=True) # receives request from php
for j in json:
        print str(j)

test = [{'ad': j['4'], 'token':j['6']} for j in json]
```

Comment: The problem is `j['4']` where `j` is a string. Try `j[4]` instead. Do you understand that `j` is the last key in the JSON object? If the value of `j` is `"4"`, `j[4]` will fail as well but with `IndexError`. You probably want `json[0]["4"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in a `list` of `dict`s because your code tries to process a list of dicts. The problem isn't related to json, that just happens to be how you read in the data structure. Here's your code as a single script demonstrating the problem. I changed the name to `data` to avoid confusion with `json` and I'm using `repr` instead of `str` to keep the problem clear.

```
data = {'4': 5, '6': 7}

for j in data:
        print repr(j)

test = [{'ad': j['ad'], 'token':j['token']} for j in data]
```

Running this results in

```
'4'
'6'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 6, in <module>
    test = [{'ad': j['ad'], 'token':j['token']} for j in data]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Your print statement shows that iterating through `data` produces strings so it makes sense that `j['token']` will fail. From the looks of your code, it seems like you want to create a list of dicts from a list of dicts as input. And once you put the input dicts in a list, it ... well crashes because the dicts don't have the keys you claim... but is closer!

Comment: Hi tdelaney, thanks very much for deconstructing this for me, I have a follow up question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093533/iterating-through-key-value-pairs-in-a-python-dictionary