# Iterating through key value pairs in a python dictionary to build an list of objects

Tags: python, json, flask

[image]

I need to post some objects to a flask app where, with each object made of 2 key-value pairs.

I'm using postman to test sending 1 object as json, but I need the ability to send multiple objects ( again each of which are made of 2 kv pairs as in screenshot )

My flask app looks like:

```
json = request.get_json(force=True) # receives request from postman
for j in json:
        print str(j)

test = [{'a': j['key1'], 'token':j['key2']} for j in json ]
```

I would like rebuild the json into a list ('test') of dictionaries with dic containing 2 kv pairs (i.e. each dic is an object).

Unfortunately I realized that because json above is

```
{u'key2': u'xyz', u'key1': u'abc'}
```

I'm getting:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

please see [TypeError: string indices must be integers with flask json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34073939/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-with-flask-json/34074297#34074297)

In this case there is only 1 object, but How can I iterate through the json variable to build the list of dics I need?

Comment: Perhaps you need to `import json` and use `json.loads` to convert what you're retrieving into a dictionary so that `j['key1']` is valid?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, I'm not sure I understand. {u'key2': u'xyz', u'key1': u'abc'} is already a dic. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: You are iterating over the keys of the dict.

Comment: You want to send multiple objects... how do you plan to do that? It would make sense to put them into a list and your script is built to handle lists. So, it seems to me that the problem is the test data you are sending via postman. Just put it in a list, and everything works. Your problem is bad test data.

Comment: Thank you, that's true the posted json does work when placed into [] in postman, I was just looking for a way to make the code a little more fault tolerant and able to handle both single and multiple objects .

Answer (score 1):

Let me de-construct your code assuming `json` is a dictionary with the data `{u'key2': u'xyz', u'key1': u'abc'}`

```
test = [{'a': j['key1'], 'token':j['key2']} for j in json ]
```

What you were actually doing is iterating through the key in the dictionary and then treating the result as a dictionary, this will give you an error!

The `j` in `json` in each loop is the key, so in the first iteration you get the result `'key1'` and when you try `j['key1']` you assumed that `j` is a dictionary, but in fact it is a string, hence the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

This is probably what you are looking for to help you with your solution.

This will give you a list of dictionaries:

```
test = [{key, value} for key, value in json.items()]
```

The result:

```
[{u'key2': u'xyz'}, {u'key1': u'abc'}]
```

The reason your code failed is because you were *trying to* unnecessarily iterate through the dictionary, but if you wish to disassemble it simply do this:

```
[dict(a=json['key1'], token=json['key2'])]
```

Result:

```
[{'a': u'abc', 'token': u'xyz'}]
```

Comment: Thank you vsachar, thats very helpful and I finally understand the reason for  the error, However I am actually looking for the data to be stored like [{'a': u'abc', 'token': u'xyz'}] not [{'a': u'abc'}, {'token': u'xyz'}], with each dictionary having multiple key-vals and representing 1 object.

Comment: What do you mean by an object? Is this data `{u'key2': u'xyz', u'key1': u'abc'}` an object to you? I can modify the code above to give you the result you are looking for but do you have to handle this situation just once or does it repeat?

Comment: @user61629 I have made some changes to the code to give you you a since dictionary with new keys.

Comment: Sorry test = [dict(a=json['key1'], token=json['key2'])] gives the same error : TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: According to the test data you have given the code should work, if however the json looks like `[{u'key2': u'xyz', u'key1': u'abc'}]` (a dictionary contained within a list) then the code above would not work. I'm very confused as to why your test data keeps changing from a dictionary to a list.

Answer (score 1):

*I was just looking for a way to make the code a little more fault tolerant and able to handle both single and multiple objects*

The easy way to do that is to check the type of data coming in and change it into a standardized form that the rest of your code can consume. If you get a `dict` just create a `list` to hold the `dict` and the rest of the code will work.

```
json = request.get_json(force=True) # receives request from postman
for j in json:
        print str(j)

if isinstance(json, dict):
    json = [json]
test = [{'a': j['key1'], 'token':j['key2']} for j in json ]
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a great idea!